# Msmq authentication from asp.net site

Tags: security, msmq

If you have an asp.net site sending messages to a remote queue, how do you handle authentication. If Windows Authentication is turned off, the network service sends a message to the remote queue. Does that mean that in de security tab of the queue, I need to add the netwerk service of the server sending the message? (by the way, I do not use http or https).

And what if Windows Authentication is enabled, do I need to add all users that will log in using windows authentication to the queue?